# mySQL Table Join - Wrong Answer

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm quite new to mySQL queries and struggling to achieve the result I require.
I have two tables of user information that I need to present. The tables are as follows:

```
users
+----+------------------+
| id | email            | 
+----+------------------+
|  1 |  joe@hotmail.com |
|  2 | john@hotmail.com |
|  3 | fred@hatmail.com |
+----+------------------+

user_detail
+----------+--------+--------+
| detailid | userid | detail | 
+----------+--------+--------+
|    1     |   1    | Joe    |
|    2     |   1    | Soap   |
|    1     |   2    | John   |
|    2     |   2    | Doe    |
|    1     |   3    | Fred   |
|    2     |   3    | Bloggs |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

I have constructed the following query which joins the tables:

```
SELECT id, detail , email
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_detail
ON users.id=user_detail.userid
ORDER by id
```

The query produces this result:

```
+--------+--------+------------------+
| userid | detail |    email         |
+--------+--------+------------------+
|   1    | Joe    |  joe@hotmail.com |
|   1    | Soap   |  joe@hotmail.com |
|   2    | John   | john@hotmail.com |
|   2    | Doe    | john@hotmail.com |
|   3    | Fred   | fred@hatmail.com |
|   3    | Bloggs | fred@hatmail.com |
+--------+--------+------------------+
```

What I'm struggling to achieve is this:

```
+--------+---------+---------+------------------+
| userid | detail1 | detail2 |    email         |
+--------+---------+---------+------------------+
|   1    |  Joe    | Soap    | joe@hotmail.com  |
|   2    |  John   | Doe     | john@hotmail.com |
|   3    |  Fred   | Bloggs  | fred@hatmail.com |
+--------+---------+---------+------------------+
```

Could you please help and point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
MAX(CASE WHEN detaildid=1 THEN detail END) as detail1,
MAX(CASE WHEN detaildid=2 THEN detail END) as detail2,
email
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_detail
ON users.id=user_detail.userid
GROUP BY id,email
ORDER by id
```

This can be written dynamically if you have many detailids.

Comment: Wow - You've introduced me to a whole new SQL code area I had no idea of. Many thanks. Looks like I've got a new area of learning to investigate.

Comment: @talkpoppycock Search for mysql pivot if you want to know more.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the same table twice, once for detail id 1 and another instance for detail id 2

```
SELECT id, d1.detail, d2.detail, email
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_detail d1
ON u.id = d1.userid
AND d1.detailid = 1
LEFT JOIN user_detail d2
ON u.id = d2.userid
AND d2.detailid = 2
ORDER BY ID
```